# How to assign local machines into Mikrotik Router?

Tags: vmware-esxi, port-forwarding, rdp, mikrotik

I have a Dedicated Server and installed a VMWare-Esxi as main OS on it.

Then, I added 4 VMs on VMWare-Esxi :

```
VM1 - Windows Server 2008 - Local IP  192.168.100.10
VM2 - Windows Server 2008 - Local IP  192.168.100.11
VM3 - Windows Server 2008 - Local IP  192.168.100.12
VM4 - Mikrotik Router 6.6 - Public IP 149.252.96.29   // definitely it's not my real IP :)
```

**What I want to do?**

I want to implement port forwarding on Mikrotik Router to Local VMs like so :

> 149.252.96.29:1573  *== forward to => 192.168.100.10:3389*
>
> 149.252.96.29:1574  *== forward to => 192.168.100.11:3389*
>
> 149.252.96.29:1575  *== forward to => 192.168.100.12:3389*

**The main question :**

The main question is that I don't know how to add the VMs with local IP to the Mikrotik Router?

Any helps would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `Dnat` action on `nat` tab of `firewall` like this:

```
/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat  dst-address=149.252.96.29 protocol=tcp dst-port=1573 action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.100.10 to-ports=3389
/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat  dst-address=149.252.96.29 protocol=tcp dst-port=1574 action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.100.11 to-ports=3389
/ip firewall nat add chain=dstnat  dst-address=149.252.96.29 protocol=tcp dst-port=1575 action=dst-nat to-addresses=192.168.100.12 to-ports=3389
```

> Ofcourse you should have an IP address in range of 192.168.100.x on the mikrotik to be able to contact with servers.

-

> And possibly if you have some Deny rules on mikrotik Firewall here is
>   the code to allow these connection to pass through:

```
/ip firewall filter add place-before=0 chain=forward protocol=tcp dst-port=3389 action=accept
```